# Error: dot: can't open ast.dot: No such file or directory ...While creating a pdf file with graphviz using python

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from a .dot file, I'm using python and the IDE pycharm but for some reason it is giving me that error, I already have Graphviz installed.

This is the code I used to generate the .pdf file but it gives me the error

```
 dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
direcc = os.path.join(dirname, 'ast.dot')
file = open(direcc, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(graph)
file.close()
os.system('dot -T pdf -o ast.pdf ast.dot')
```

The code generates the ast.dot file tough. But when trying to generate the pdf file is when I get the error.

I already have Grpahviz added to me Environment Variables

[image]

[image]

Not sure what the problem is since I've created images and pdf files using graphviz in other programming languages. I'm using Pycharm's latest version, not sure if it has something to do with this issue.

[image: The code generates the ast.dot file]

[image: This is the only error I get]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Also, please include the complete traceback from Python.

Comment: Probably your working directory / directory where dot is run is different from the directory where your current `__file__` resides. What happens when you prepend  `dirname` to `ast.pdf` and `ast.dot`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still does not work, Not sure what else I can do

Comment: Please add the changed code and the error messages you get or do you get the same error message? Why did you open a new question (looks like under a slightly user name though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246172/error-while-generating-a-pdf-file-in-python-using-graphviz